# How to call REST API with Retrofit @Query

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I can't get data base on idCafe.

This is the url from webservice :

https://admin-services-dot-annular-bucksaw-167705.appspot.com/_ah/api/meja?idCafe=123445

Api Service Interface :

```
@GET ("meja?idCafe")
fun getTable(@Query("idCafe") idCafe: String): Call<List<Table>>
```

I call api with this function :

```
private fun getTableList(idCafe:String){
    val apiService : Service = Client.getClient()!!.create(Service::class.java)
    apiService.getTable(idCafe).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Table>>{

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Table>>?, response: Response<List<Table>>?) {

            Log.i("IdMeja", "id : " + response?.body())
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
                val listTable = response.body()
                if (listTable == null || listTable.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Tidak ada meja", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else{
                    tableList = ArrayList(listTable)
                    // update list table
                    dataAdapter.updateData(tableList)
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.i("idCafe", " $idCafe")
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Gagal dapat meja", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Table>>?, t: Throwable?) {

            Log.i("fail",t.toString() )
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

But the response unsuccessful. I can get idCafe, but can't get data of Table.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show the logs of the error

Comment: post the orginal endpoint imean the real url...and post the log errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
@GET ("meja")
fun getTable(@Query("idCafe") idCafe: Int): Call<List<Table>>
```

You dont have to include **?** and **query variable** inside your URL.

Comment: it retrun error like this 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT'.

Comment: show you response json? which you will get from that url.

Comment: here your signature getting `<List<Table>>` which is array but actual result come in Object.  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT error means

Comment: this is the response json

Comment: {
    "daftarMeja": [
        {
            "nama": "1",
            "tersedia": true,
            "id": "5648554290839552"
        },
        {
            "nama": "2",
            "tersedia": true,
            "id": "5769015641243648"
        },
        {
            "nama": "3",
            "tersedia": true,
            "id": "5687539843203072"
        },
}

Comment: Post your response json in question and see it is begin with Object `{ "daftarMeja":`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@Query` Retrofit will build the query parameter for you. No need to specify it in the URL.

This means that you should just declare the interface like:

```
@GET ("meja")
fun getTable(@Query("idCafe") idCafe: String): Call<List<Table>>
```

Retrofit will then use the name inside the annotation - idCafe - and build the parameter with it.

You can keep using string, since retrofit can easily deal with it. However, if `idCafe` is better modeled as an integer in your application, then I'd suggest you use `Int` instead:

```
@GET ("meja")
fun getTable(@Query("idCafe") idCafe: Int): Call<List<Table>>
```

Note that this is only possible because in the URL `idCafe` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Call your api like this

```
@GET ("meja")
fun getTable(@Query("idCafe") idCafe: String): Call<TableResponse>
```

And the table response call will be as follows -

```
class TableResponse {
     @SerializedName("daftarMeja")
     List<Table> list;

     public List<Table> getList() {
          return list;
     }

     public void setList(List<Table> list) {
          this.list = list;
     }
}
```

You can not use `Call<List<Table>>` as an result in the api call as error says "BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT"